# Creating a Flip Card animation in android studio using java

Tags: java, android

I am learning mobile development using android studio and Java. I tried to implement a flip card animation to build a flip card memory like game (without a library) and without expanding to another activity. I am basically using a function to flip the image then replace it, but the image gets replaced then it rotates. Find the code i worked on below. The function will later support flipping back the images if the flipped 2 images do not match, or increase a score by 1 if they match.

```
    public void flipCard(View view){
         ImageView card = (ImageView) view;
         card.animate().rotationYBy(180);
         card.SetImageResource(R.drawable.ex1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the image after the completion of the flip animation you have to use the [withEndAction(Runnable runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable)) method of `ViewPropertyAnimator`.

Example is like below:

```
public void flipCard(View view){
    ImageView card = (ImageView) view;
    card.setImageResource(0);
    card.animate().rotationYBy(180).withEndAction(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            card.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        }
    });
}
```

To revert back the two images after a certain time you can change the `rotationYBy to -180` and you can use the `setStartDelay` method to start the animation after an amount of time in milliseconds.

Example is like below:

```
public void flipCardToInitialState(View view){
    ImageView card = (ImageView) view;
    card.animate().rotationYBy(-180).setStartDelay(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            card.setImageResource(0);
        }
    });
}
```

And you can use it in case the two images do not match like below:

```
flipCardToInitialState(imageView1);
flipCardToInitialState(imageView2);
```

You can also use `Handler().postDelayed` to flip the two images back after a certain time in milliseconds:

```
//flip the 2 images
flipCard(imageView1);
flipCard(imageView2);

//and if the don't match flip the back after a certain of time in milliseconds
if(theyDontMatch)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    flipCardToInitialState(imageView1);
                    flipCardToInitialState(imageView2);
                }
            }, 2000); //flip them back after 2 seconds delay
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do it such that the 2 flipped images revert back to place after a certain time if they do not match. Thank you!

Comment: Of course you can revert the 2 images back check updated answer.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much! i will try and fix my approach.